# How to use a SpringBoot project as a shared library in microservice project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, microservices

I have those projects in my microservice architecture:

--`account` (first microservice)

--`loan` (second microservice)

--`shared` (SpringBoot project)

`account` microservice and `loan` microservice use a common Pojo class in the `shared` project.

How can I configure the `pom.xml` of `account` and `card` microservices to use the `shared` project?

Comment: Simply define a dependency to `shared` but if that is really spring boot project which means having configured `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in that part you can't use it ... because it will be packging the final spring boot app which can not being used as a library... but there not enough information etc. to make a good answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question:

1- Go to `pom.xml` in `shared` project and add this:

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>origin</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

2- Inside the folder where exists the `pom.xml` in the `shared` project execute this:

```
mvn clean install
```

3- Go inside `shared` folder and Install the jar (change the `file`, `groupId` and the `artifactId`):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./target/shared-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-origin.jar -DgroupId=com.anchtun -DartifactId=shared -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

4- Go inside `account` project and add in `pom.xml` this dependency (change the `groupId` and the `artifactId`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.anchtun</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

5- You can use the `jar` now!

[image]

6- When you try to create the other jar (in `other-service` that uses the `shared.jar`) do:

```
mvn initialize
```

then

```
mvn clean install
```